# ACPI tables information

Tags: unix

What information is present in the ACPI tables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ACPI tables are the central data structure of an ACPI-based system. They contain definition blocks that describe all the hardware that can be managed through ACPI. These definition blocks include both data and machine-independent byte-code that is used to perform hardware management operations.
courtesy = http://www.usenix.org/event/usenix02/tech/freenix/full_papers/watanabe/watanabe_html/node4.html

Answer (score 0):

The ACPI tables are collection of tables like FADT,DSDT,MADT,XSDT and so on.
Each of these tables are arranged in the form of bit fields that can be read or they contain AML data(example the DSDT tables which contain AML stuff).

Each table gives some information,depending on what you are looking for. For exampple the MADT tables contain information about APIC ID's ,Local APIC processors.

I would highly recommend reading the ACPI Spec. It is the most authoritative and complete guide in this matter.
See http://www.acpi.info/spec50.htm for the spec

Additonally you can use the userland ACPI tool called acpidump.

Selecting the -d option enables displaying DSDT tables. See http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=acpidump&sektion=8 for acpidump